# Unable to understand JmeterUtils properties

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, throughput

I am trying to put load from my java application using Apache's JMeterUtils. I am new to Jmeter , I am a bit confused about the values I should put in to acheive 72k load in 2hours.

```
load.throughput.max=100 (load put per sec ?)
load.thread-count-in-group=25 (total number of threads runnings)
load.duration.seconds=7200 (load will run for 2hours)
load.ramp-up.duration.seconds=20 (time to bring all threads up)
```

Is my understanding correct about these properties ? I was referring to below documentation  [JMeterUtils](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/branches/rel-2-2/docs/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#loadProperties(java.lang.String)) but was not able to find any thing about these properties. Can somebody please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to "put load" using [JMeterUtils](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html), it's just a helper class which allows you to set and get [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)

The "load" is generated by the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) where you can set the desired number of threads (virtual users), ramp-up period, number of iterations, duration, etc.

Once started each thread begins executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as it can.

So if you need to execute 72000 requests in 2 hours with 25 users you need the following setup:

1. Thread Group with 25 users, unlimited iteratinos and 2 hours duration:

   [image]
2. A Sampler which will be executing the real work, i.e. sending a request to the system under test. A very minimal one which sends simple single GET request to http://example.com is below

   [image]
3. A [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) to limit JMeter to send requests at 10 requests per second rate

   [image]

If you need to start the test from your Java application you can either run an existing [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) like outlined above using [StandardJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/StandardJMeterEngine.html) class or create the test from scratch using relevant JMeter API classes ([ThreadGroup](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html), [TestPlan](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestPlan.html), [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), etc.)

If you want to use properties which are set by your JMeterUtils class you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(load.thread-count-in-group,)}`

[image]